# in CQ5 , How to connect an External Database in place of JCR?

Tags: mysql, database, jcr, crx, aem

I have to connect an External Database ( MySQL ) in place of the inbuilt Content Repository that is called JCR in CQ5 . I am unable to do it . 
Please give ideas . Suggestions are invited.

Komal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664639/external-database-with-adobe-cq5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/Development/HowToConfigureSlingDatasource.html