# external database with Adobe CQ5?

Tags: mysql, database, adobe, external, aem

Is there any way to connect external data base like **mysql** can be connected to **Adobe CQ5**?

JCR(Java Content Repository) in Adobe cq5 now by default connects to H2 database...how to make it use sql/mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to: /system/console/configMgr
Open up: the JDBC Connections Pool configuration
Enter all the standard JDBC config elements (username, password, driver, JDBC URI)
Enter a Datasource Name (referred to below as yourDataSourceName)

In your JSP or Servlet:

```
<%@ page import="com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourcePool" %>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.DataSource" %>

DataSourcePool dbService = sling.getService(DataSourcePool.class);
DataSource ds = (DataSource) dbService.getDataSource("yourDataSourceName");

if(ds != null) {
   try {
      %><sql:query var="result" sql="SELECT now()" dataSource="<%=ds%>" /><%
   } catch (Exception e) { } 
}
```

Comment: There's also a helpful guide posted on how to configure database connections on the CQ documentation site. http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/Development/HowToConfigureSlingDatasource.html