# How to use normal ajax request on any jsp/servlet to get response

Tags: aem

I want to create login form in CQ5 using normal JSP & AJAX request with database. Can any one tell me the steps how to use normal JSP and AJAX in CQ5?

Answer (score 1):

At the server-side, an AJAX handler can be implemented the same way as an HTML handler, in CQ5. Create your CQ template with a standard backing component. In your component, code your JSP as your normally would, following CQ best practices such as including "/libs/foundation/global.jsp" (or your overridden version of this). You'll have access to all normal JSP objects such as request and response. global.jsp also includes JSTL, so you've got access to standard taglibs.

As for connecting to a database, see my other answer, [External Database with Adobe CQ5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664639/external-database-with-adobe-cq5/7391688#7391688).